# Searching for specific value under registry subkey

Tags: registry, installshield, installscript

using InstallShield 2008 Premier I am looking to be able to search for a specific String in a key in the Windows registry. My challenge is that there are subfolders in the path to the key that can be unknown. For example, in this registry path: **`HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\GUID`** 
I may not necessarily know the name of the GUID folder, but I need to look for a particular String in a **`DisplayName`** key, to see if it exists under one of the GUID folders. Is there a command in InstallShield 2008 that can search for that String from the **`Uninstall`** folder level down?

I know there are commands like **`RegDBKeyExist`** but it looks like you need to provide specific folder names in the entire path to do searches. If anyone has run into this situation and can assist it would be greatly appreciated.
 Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as you referring to `RegDBKeyExist` InstallScript function I assume you are looking for example written with InstallScript language.

To enumerate subkeys of the known key you would want to use `RegDBQueryKey` function. After enumerating subkeys of your path `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` you would need to loop through the list and query `DisplayName` key value to compare it with particular string. This may be done by using `RegDBGetKeyValueEx` function. The example of enumerating through the registry subkeys is over there: [RegDBQueryKey Example](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield19helplib/Subsystems/installshield19langref/helplibrary/LangrefRegDBQueryKey_example.htm).

If your project is basic MSI without Installscript support you may want to create Custom Action(CA) with regular VisualBasic script. There are plenty examples on how to enumerate registry keys with VBScript.

Comment: I completely skipped over RegDBQueryKey, which is odd because I have used that before!! Thank you for your reply Slava!

Comment: @Randy Glad it helped, Randy.